# Render Ember Sub-Routes While In Parent Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

What is the correct way to render sub routes while at the parent route? Basically what I'm trying to do is create a table of resources from the parent route but then make the rows "editable" while at their specific sub-route. Examples:

- /foos = table of all foo's but each row is a render of /foos/#
- /foos/1 = same table of /foos but the specific row is now form fields for editing
- /foos/new = row with blank form fields for a new foo (not part of the question, explain below)

The idea is that only one row is "editable" at a time. So if a user navigates from /foos/new to /foos/3 then the "new" row goes away and the foo # 3 is now editable. Similar when navigating between specific /foos/#

Bonus points: What is the best way for the /foos/# route to know if it is active, so the template knows to either display the read-only foo details or form fields for editing.

At this point I have (what I think is) mostly setup for this scenario but am stuck at the rendering sub routes. I have a jsbin setup: http://jsbin.com/jayax/6/

Comment: How important is it that the row is editable at a particular URL as opposed to just editable one at a time? I'm working on a solution for you, and getting them editable at the proper URL is easy, but I'm running into a snag trying to get them uneditable once you've left their respective URL

Comment: I would take a solution like that too. That is actually the heart of  my issue, only one row to be editable at a time (including the /new route). Thanks!